# How to not install MacPorts dependency if installed elsewhere?

Tags: macos, macports

A common problem that I'm having with MacPorts is that I will go to install a port, and it will list a port as a dependency that I have installed outside of MacPorts.

For example:

I have Qt5 installed outside of MacPorts, and I absolute do not want MacPorts to install Qt4, but it is a dependency for the port I want. I want the port to use Qt5 libraries which I have installed in another location.

Also, I have Python 2.7.5 and Python 3 installed outside of MacPorts. However, when I go to install some ports that have Python as a dependancy, MacPorts tries to install port `python27` — I do not want this port installed. I want to manage Python versions outside of  MacPorts.

What are my options?

Answer (score 3):

In general, MacPorts uses only a small collection of “system” libraries and tools; it really has no facility for using separately built libraries, tools, environments, etc.

See the entries titled “[Why is MacPorts using its own libraries?](https://trac.macports.org/wiki/FAQ#ownlibs)” and “[Will MacPorts link to system libraries rather than its own?](https://trac.macports.org/wiki/FAQ#syslibs)” in the [MacPorts FAQ](https://trac.macports.org/wiki/FAQ).

---

You might be able to adjust individual Portfiles to use your already-built stuff, but you will really be working “against the grain” of the MacPorts system; you will likely run into many difficulties when undertaking such an approach.

It might prove easier to just manually build the software that you are ultimately interested in; that way you have better control over which libraries it uses. If there are a lot of (non-Qt, non-Python) dependencies, and if you do not mind building them through MacPorts, then you could still use MacPorts to provide other dependencies:

```
 # make sure the list of other dependencies looks reasonable
port echo depof:someport and not python27 and not qt4-mac

# install the other dependencies
sudo port install depof:someport and not python27 and not qt4-mac

# configure; the way to specify the library locations will vary, but might be like this:
CFLAGS=-I/opt/local/include LDFLAGS=-L/opt/local/lib \
  ./configure --with-qt=/my/qt5/installation --with-python3=/my/python3/installation
```